# Nodejs is not installing by nvm in arch linux

Tags: node.js, archlinux

I am in arch linux.
I have downloaded `nvm` .
But when i am trying to install `node` by `nvm install node` . Shell giving this error

````
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/nvm/alias’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/nvm/alias’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/nvm/alias’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/nvm/alias’: Permission denied
Downloading and installing node v19.5.0...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/nvm/.cache’: Permission denied
creating directory /usr/share/nvm/.cache/bin/node-v19.5.0-linux-x64/files failed
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v19.5.0/node-v19.5.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to open the file
Warning: /usr/share/nvm/.cache/bin/node-v19.5.0-linux-x64/node-v19.5.0-linux-x6
Warning: 4.tar.xz: No such file or directory
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v19.5.0/node-v19.5.0-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /usr/share/nvm/.cache/bin/node-v19.5.0-linux-x64/node-v19.5.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/nvm/.cache’: Permission denied
creating directory /usr/share/nvm/.cache/src/node-v19.5.0/files failed
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v19.5.0/node-v19.5.0.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to open the file
Warning: /usr/share/nvm/.cache/src/node-v19.5.0/node-v19.5.0.tar.xz: No such
Warning: file or directory
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v19.5.0/node-v19.5.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /usr/share/nvm/.cache/src/node-v19.5.0/node-v19.5.0.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.```
````

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to prepend `sudo` to your command since it is attempting to install `node` globally in `/usr/share/´.

Try `sudo nvm install node` and see if that helps. If it doesn't, see who you are issuing the command as with `whoami` and then check the permissions of `/usr/share` with `ls -l /usr/share` to see if it has changed to something non-default by mistake.